# Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException Filesystem exception:

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, command-line, dependency

As I ran the command `composer require -w` as part of the process to upgrade Magento 2.4.2 to 2.4.4, I found the error seen in the image below.

[image]

Below is the article I'm referring to upgrade Magento.

https://www.mgt-commerce.com/tutorial/how-to-upgrade-magento-2-4-3-to-magento-2-4-4/

I request someone to share the list of commands to be run to upgrade Magento to 2.4.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permission to copy file from `/home/magento/.cache/composer/composer-temp.phar` into `/usr/bin/composer`

You can use `sudo composer self-update` for overwrite `/usr/bin/composer` or download latest version to some another path and use like `php /home/magento/composer.phar` instead of `composer`

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Comment: Hi Victor, could you please tell me if I need to upgrade our elasticsearch to its latest version before Magento upgrade can be done?

Comment: Ideally to have related version of ElasticSearch. For 2.4.4 you can switch to OpenSearch. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Comment: Ok, we would like to stick on to Elasticsearch.

Comment: It's up to you, FYI: Magento Cloud stopped to support ElasticSearch after 7.10 and switched to OpenSearch 1.2

Comment: Thanks for the information, but we're using Magento community edition

Comment: Hi Dhiren, could you please have a look at the related post here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358323/magento-2-4-2-unable-to-process-binding-ifnot-functionreturn-customer-fu I'm struggling to fix this for over 10 days now. I added as much information about the problem as possible.